# Fear in religion

Tags: religion

I’ve looked into some other religions and from what it seems it seems like fear is the foundation/root of belief. What I mean is saying “you will get punished if you don’t do X thing” that may just be for personal benefit. This can be used to exploit others, get money etc etc. From what I understand historically this was also a big thing in religions like Christianity where it seemed people were indoctrinated and a system was in place that used fear to “put people in their places” and there were things like tithes.

Is this the same case with Islam? Even if money isn’t necessarily in the equation it seems fear is the root to belief in anything, it’s also seems to me to be the reason why people don’t branch out and stick to their own religion without questioning anything, I think this ties into something called confirmation bias too. It seems people are just devoid of skepticism and taught something at birth and roll with it fearing if they don’t there will be consequences and that’s a pretty dangerous train of thought.

Answer (score -2):

When I was a kid, I used to hear so much about haram things and punishment of hell that I thought Allah was bad and punishes more than rewards, so much that when my little sister asked me about Allah I said : Allah is not nice and he can put you in hell and he is only nice to the good muslims. Which is absolutely false, thank God my mother heard me.
This is just a proof that people talk more about the haram and the bad and hell, than heaven and the amazing mercy of Allah (SWT).
Islam is a religion of wisdom. It’s the religion of God. If God exists, and if Islam is his religion, then how can Islam be bad?
One day I did something bad and I watched some youtube videos about tawba and I didn’t have enough remorse for tawba. I looked for ways to feel remorse and all I got was : "FEAR ALLAH". Fear didn’t work, but you know what worked? Love.
Love of Allah is how you feel remorse when you commit a sin.
Think about it, if you love someone wouldn’t you be afraid to make them mad or hate you? You would fear their sadness and you would love their happiness. Exactly.
Islam is like that. Islam is a religion of wisdom and unfortunately many people talk more about the haram than the halal.
Love Allah (SWT).
And Allah knows best.